# Aggregate sum on a field when another field equals to some value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get an aggregation `sum` on a field (`primary_key`) in order to find out any `primary_key` duplicates when another field `code` equals `1111` in `mongo` shell;

```
db.results.aggregate(
{"$group": { "_id": "$primary_key", "code": "$code", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
{"$match": {"_id": {"count": {"$gt": 1}}}, "code": '1111'},
{"$sort": {"count": -1}}
)
```

i got the errors,

```
Error: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
"code" : 40323,
"codeName" : "Location40323"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
```

I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: `$match` has imbalanced braces `{}`. You are missing the closing one on the end. It's also best practice to wrap the pipeline as an array. Just like the [documentation actually telly you to do.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear without a document sample, but you appear to be looking for this:

```
db.results.aggregate(
  { "$match": { "code": '1111'} },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$primary_key", "count": {"$sum": 1} }},
  { "$match": { "count": {"$gt": 1} }},
  { "$sort": {"count": -1} }
)
```

At least based on your description.

That corrects syntax errors and a base misunderstanding that `$match` can be used multiple times. In fact so can any pipeline stage.